# Geometry nodes: How can I evenly distribute clusters of points on a cylinder

Tags: geometry-nodes

Goal:
I use the "distribute points on faces" node on faces that form a narrow cylinder (a "ring").
the points should create groups that resemble evenly distributed stripes across the ring (along the x axis).

Current solution:
Since the ring plane is parallel to the y axis i look at sin(y) of the rings position as constraint for the selection[image].

Problem:
This creates stripes but they get wider and wider towards the "sides" of the ring.
How do I formulate this logic so that the stripes width is constant?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using distribute points on faces, you can use mesh to points node. That way you can convert each face to a point and instance the stripes on them. Capture the normals first so you can rotate the instances accordingly

[image]

Comment: I prefer your solution because its ultimately easier to create faces in the shape i need first and then put points on them. directly controlling the point distribution is difficult and vague. In the end i got some nice striped forests on my spacestation: https://imgur.com/a/hbo8f14

Answer (score 1):

tbh this is more a mathematical than a geometry nodes question...but anyway.

The trick is here to use the angle, so that you can get an even distribution:

[image]

Comment: Im sorry i couldnt reproduce your result at all in Blender 4.0.1 https://imgur.com/a/34XWrNb

Comment: then pls use exactly (!) my node tree ...and not something different. thx. and of course it depends on what the size of the cylinder is.